# Prometheus monitoring pods in Kubernetes cluster fail to dcp dial connection refused

Tags: kubernetes, containers, monitoring, prometheus, kubernetes-pod

I'm trying to scrape pods in my kubernetes cluster. I have deployed prometheus with `helm install prometheus stable/prometheus -n monitoring` command to set it in the monitoring namespace.

I'm trying to apply recommanded instructions to scrape pods by adding annotations inside pods elements :

```
kubectl edit pod nfs-provisioner-nfs-client-provisioner-648b66fc7c-w2btj -n storage
```

adding :

```
metadata:
  annotations:
    prometheus.io/path: /metrics
    prometheus.io/port: "8080"
    prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
```

as mentionned in this link: https://hub.helm.sh/charts/stable/prometheus

but for whatever reason I cannot figure out to solve, I get a connection refused in prometheus target dashboard

STATE DOWN and `Get http://10.233.96.18:8080/metrics: dial tcp 10.233.96.18:8080: connect: connection refused` as error :

[TCP DIAL CONNECTION REFUSED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUuHY.png)

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Do those IP addresses actually belong to your Pods? Is 8080 the port number through which the Pod service is reachable? Can you access those ports from anywhere at all?

Comment: Have you checked connectivity to this pod from a different pod? What are the results? This is clearly a connectivity issue and as @LaszloValko said, please, make sure that IP and Port are correct.

Comment: my bad ! I wasn't targeting an opened port. I need to get ports matching to my config file so its working now. Thanks for help